# how to use cpio related commands in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to use cpio related commands in playbook like  cpio -imdv .
Which ansible module has to be used for CPIO commands.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use a simple command?

```
- name: Execute the command in remote shell
  shell: cpio -imdv
```